# Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity unclear

Tags: android

In the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html#DirectEntry) there are 2 steps described to preserve navigation:

- Add the following to the manifest: **android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"**
- Create a back stack based on the Intent that starts the Activity

For me it was enough to add the suggested to the manifest, the 2nd step does not change anything, so I'm not understanding what's the point of the 2nd. step, or if the documentation isn't up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The 2nd step is needed for it to work on API<17. Starting with API17 only the manifest setting is needed.